# What is the most robust way to detect light reflections on the object

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

The task I am working on, requires the analysis of the line-lamp reflection on the object. In some cases, there is another source of light present (unintentionally) and I would like to mask the lamp reflection only.

I tried to mask the lines the following way:

```
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.medianBlur(cimg, 5)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 210, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

In some cases, this creates a good mask, whereas in some cases it fails.
Below are the two examples:

An eaxmple of desired result:

[image]
[image]

An example of bad result:

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know what is a good way to mask such light reflections?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [top-hat transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-hat_transform) is the most appropriate tool to isolate such lines from the background gradient.

The top-hat is a filter from Mathematical Morphology. It is defined as the difference between the image and its opening.

For example, from your second image I get:

[image: isolated line]

I used an opening with a disk of diameter 10 pixels. You need to pick a diameter that is wider than the thing you want to isolate, but smaller than any variation in the background. In this case, the background is a simple gradient so anything is smaller than it.

Note that the input image had some significant JPEG compression artifacts, which affect the result you see here. The output will be much better with a better input image quality.